# Integration of a subprocess definition in JBPM JPDL

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jbpm

I'm using the process definition language jPDL from the JBoss Workflow engine : jBPM.

I want to integrate a very simple **process** definition graph : Basically, I have a main process definition (*simple/processdefinition.xml*) including :

- a Start node,
- a Process State node,
- an End node.

Here is the definition of the graph :

```
<process-definition 
  xmlns="urn:jbpm.org:jpdl-3.2"
  name="simple">
   <start-state name="start">
        <transition name="to_state" to="process-state">
         <action name="action" class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
            <message>
                    Going to the sub-state!
                </message>
         </action>
      </transition>
        <event type="node-leave">
            <action class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
                <message>
                    Start.
                </message>
            </action>
        </event>
   </start-state>
   <process-state name="process-state">
        <sub-process name="subsimple" binding="late"/>
        <variable access="read,write" name="message" mapped-name="message">        </variable>
        <event type="node-enter">
            <action class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler"></action>
        </event>
        <transition to="end" name="to_end"></transition>
    </process-state>
   <end-state name="end">
        <event type="node-enter">
            <action class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
                <message>
                    End.
                </message>
            </action>
        </event>
    </end-state>
</process-definition>
```

Within the Process State node I defined a **Sub-Process** graph (*subsimple/processdefinition.xml*) containing :

- a Start node,
- a State node,
- an End node.

Here is the definition of the graph :

```
<process-definition 
  xmlns="urn:jbpm.org:jpdl-3.2"
  name="subsimple">
   <start-state name="start">
        <transition name="to_state" to="first">
         <action name="action" class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
            <message>Going to the first state!</message>
         </action>
      </transition>
        <event type="node-leave">
            <action class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
                <message>
                    Start.
                </message>
            </action>
        </event>
   </start-state>
   <state name="first">
      <event type="node-enter">
            <action class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
                <message>
                    In first state !!
                </message>
            </action>
        </event>
        <transition name="to_end" to="end">
         <action name="action" class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
            <message>
                    About to go out of sub-process !
                </message>
         </action>
      </transition>
   </state>
   <end-state name="end">
        <event type="node-enter">
            <action class="com.sample.action.MessageActionHandler">
                <message>
                    End.
                </message>
            </action>
        </event>
    </end-state>
</process-definition>
```

Here is the **ActionHandler** allocated to every events and transitions :

```
public class MessageActionHandler implements ActionHandler {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String message;

    public void execute(ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {
        context.getContextInstance().setVariable("message", message);

        System.out.println(context.getContextInstance().getVariable("message"));
    }
}
```

Eventually, here is the **Main class** from which I start the whole process :

```
public class testJBPM {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProcessDefinition processDefinition = ProcessDefinition
            .parseXmlResource("simple/processdefinition.xml");

    // Create an instance of the process definition.
    ProcessInstance instance = new ProcessInstance(processDefinition);

    // Move the process instance from its start state to the first state.
    instance.signal();

    // Move the process instance to the end state.
    instance.signal();
}
}
```

As I read on JBoss forum, I correctly set `binding=late` on sub-process binding in main process definition. Then I tried different ways to instanciate the process definition of the sub-process but I always get the following Exception when trying to enter the sub-state/sub-process node :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jbpm.JbpmException: can't create a process instance     when processDefinition is null
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.<init>(ProcessInstance.java:128)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.<init>(ProcessInstance.java:92)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.createSubProcessInstance(Token.java:624)
    at org.jbpm.graph.node.ProcessState.execute(ProcessState.java:164)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.enter(Node.java:319)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition.take(Transition.java:151)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.Node.leave(Node.java:394)
    at org.jbpm.graph.node.StartState.leave(StartState.java:70)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:195)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token.signal(Token.java:140)
    at org.jbpm.graph.exe.ProcessInstance.signal(ProcessInstance.java:271)
    at com.sample.main.testJBPM.main(testJBPM.java:21)
```

Can anybody give me advices on how to manage sub-process definition and use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way-out by myself :

- First, only one `instance.signal();` is necessary to impulse the whole processes trail in `main()`.
- Then, an interface has to be implemented to allow jBPM to search and instanciate the required sub-processes :

  ```
  public class DbSubProcessResolver implements SubProcessResolver {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

          public ProcessDefinition findSubProcess(Element subProcessElement) {

              String name = subProcessElement.attributeValue("name").replaceAll(
                  "\\.", "");
              ProcessDefinition subProcessDefinition = ProcessDefinition
                  .parseXmlResource(name + "/processdefinition.xml");

              return subProcessDefinition;
          }
  }
  ```
- Eventually, a jBPM configuration file has to be specified to map the jBPM framework resolver to the implemented one :

  ```
  <jbpm-configuration>
      <bean name="jbpm.sub.process.resolver" class="com.sample.resolver.DbSubProcessResolver" />
  </jbpm-configuration>
  ```

... and it works fine !